# How to redirect requests to another host using ZAP?

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm new to ZAP and I don't know much about it's js/ecma scripting.

Basically, I was trying to redirect request to another host.
Say an application that is connected to the ZAP proxy makes a request in a URL:

http://www.somesite.com/path/to/a/file

but I want to change the hostname in the URL to:
another.site.com

so it will actually request to: http://www.anothersite.com/path/to/a/file

Here's the code that I was trying to work but the URL remains unchanged in the request.

```
function proxyRequest(msg) {
    // Debugging can be done using println like this
    var uri = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString()
    var host =  msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().getHost().toString()

    print('proxyResponse called for url=' + uri)

    if (host == 'download.qt.io') {
        uri = uri.replace('download.qt.io/online/', 'mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/qt/online/')
        msg.getRequestHeader().setHeader('Location', uri)
        print('proxyRequest changed to url=' + uri)
    }

    if (host == 'ftp.jaist.ac.jp') {
        uri = uri.replace('ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/qtproject/online/', 'mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/qt/online/')
        msg.getRequestHeader().setHeader('Location', uri)
        print('proxyRequest changed to url=' + uri)
    }

    if (host == 'qtproject.mirror.liquidtelecom.com') {
        uri = uri.replace('qtproject.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/online/', 'mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/qt/online/')
        msg.getRequestHeader().setHeader('Location', uri)
        print('proxyRequest changed to url=' + uri)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually changed the request. You got the url and replaced it but then set it in the Location header like you want a redirect. You didn't actually change the request.

Comment: @kingthorin I have no idea how this works, can you tell me how to actually change the request?

Comment: I'll add a full answer later with various examples (script, replacer, host file entry). In the meantime it might be easier for you to accomplish this with a Replacer rule. https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/replacer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Replacer Rule**

Install the Replacer addon, from the marketplace:
[image: ZAP toolbar marketplace button]

1. Goto the Tools menu and select 'Replacer Options'.
2. Setup a rule as shown in the following screenshot.
3. Save/Okay as appropriate.
4. Now when your browse etc all your traffic will be redirected/rewritten.

[image: Suggested Replacer rule details]

**Option 2: HttpSender Script**

1. Create a new HttpSender script, similar to the following example:

```js
function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
  var host = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().getHost();
  if (host.equals("www.somesite.com")) {
        uri = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI();
        uri.setEscapedAuthority("www.anothersite.com");
        msg.getRequestHeader().setURI(uri);
  }
  return msg;
}

function responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper) {}
```

**Option 3: Hosts File Entry**

1. Goto a command prompt and `nslookup www.somesite.com`, note the IP address (w.x.y.z).
2. In your hosts file, add an entry associating the noted IP (w.x.y.z) with `www.anothersite.com`.
   (You may need to restart ZAP/browsers for this change to take effect. On linux you'll likely need to sudo to edit the file, on Windows you'll need to edit it as an admin user.)

(Further details WRT editing your hosts file: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)